# Using cron.d in Arch

Tags: arch-linux, cron, stability

Till now I organized my non-crontab cron-jobs by `cron.d` in Debian-LAMP environment.

My cron-jobs use me to upgrade CMSs containing my web applications.

Here's how I do it from the beginning:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<-EOF > /etc/cron.daily/cron_daily
    #!/bin/bash
    for dir in ${drt}/*/; do
        if pushd "$dir"; then
            rws
                composer update drupal/* webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies
                drush updatedb
                drush cache:rebuild
            rws
        popd
        fi
    done 2> $HOME/myErrors
EOF

cat <<-EOF > /etc/cron.weekly/cron_weekly
    #!/bin/bash
    find "$drt" -path "*/cache/*" -type f -delete
    certbot renew -q
EOF

chmod +x /etc/cron{.daily,.weekly}
```

### My question

I consider to start using Arch instead Debian.

I checked the [Arch cron documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/cron) about using `cron.d` but it's not clear to me if `cron.d` is a native part of Arch and if not, how to install it.

Is `cron.d` a part of Arch and if not, how to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/etc/cron.daily` will be available after installing `cronie` package, it is not pre-installed:

```
pacman -S cronie
```

The default system scheduled jobs in arch linux is managed through [`systemd.timer`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers). To list the timer units :

```
systemctl list-timers
```

Comment: Hi GAD3R. Would you recommend to go with the default `systemd.timer` for best stability?

Comment: @JohnDoea To use `systemd.timer` you need to create a `service` and the `timer` , some information on [Arch-linux docs : As a cron replacement](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#As_a_cron_replacement).